# Paypal php API: setting up credentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is a simple question. I am using the Paypal php api (https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/merchant-php-2.0.96.zip). I found my api keys (Api username, password and signature). But I cannot find where to specify them in express check out in the PHP SDK( I am using the Express checkout from the Samples).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify this file config/sdk_config.ini

Comment: It would be a great kindness if someone could mention the *syntax* of said modification.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sandbox api credentials as follows:

use the business account created as one of your sandbox account. (applications tab, sandbox accounts). Click on the account, then on "profile" under it, then on the "API Credentials" tab.

edit the sdk_config.ini in the php sdk (under the config folder), and use those credintials with an app_id of APP-80W284485P519543T

Make sure mode is set to sandbox under [Service] in the ini file.

When you make the service call use the account username you entered in the ini file as follows:

$setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq,"API_USERNAME");